# why running sonarqube-5.1.2 Startsonar.bat give error messages?

Tags: sonarqube

I downloaded sonarqube-5.1.2 and tried to run StartSonar.bat, then I got this error message:

```
C:\>Startsonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
Unable to open logfile ..\..\logs\sonar.log: Access is denied. (0x5)
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
Unable to open logfile ..\..\logs\sonar.log: Access is denied. (0x5)
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
Unable to open logfile ..\..\logs\sonar.log: Access is denied. (0x5)
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Unable to open logfile ..\..\logs\sonar.log: Access is denied. (0x5)
jvm 1    |
Unable to open logfile ..\..\logs\sonar.log: Access is denied. (0x5)
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Unable to open logfile ..\..\logs\sonar.log: Access is denied. (0x5)
```

I checked logs file in sonarqube-5.1.2 and this file is empty. Anyone download sonarqube-5.1.2 and has an empty logs file? Could this be the reason that I got the error message? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Check if `config/sonar.log` has required `permissions` (read/write)

Answer (score 0):

The log is telling you that the user the SonarQube platform is running as doesn't have the permissions it needs to update sonar.log. This can happen if

1. You've got some wacky "security" or encryption program "helpfully" closing down perms on files/directories on the box (I've experienced this one)
2. The SonarQube platform is running as a different user than the one you expect, i.e. some default "services" user, and that user doesn't have permissions on the file (experienced this one too).

You need to:

1. Check the SonarQube service user to make sure it's the account you expected
2. Edit the permissions on the log directory to make sure perms are granted recursively to the service user

Note that this manual permissions granting isn't a long-term fix since when you upgrade, it will be by expanding the zip for the new platform version into a new directory. The safest thing to do long-term is make sure the service runs as a user that has adequate permissions on the box - either by swapping the service to a new user or by updating the service user's groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just edited the permission on the log file. It seems it's working. At least I didn't get the "unable to open log file" error anymore.